# How to evaluate the integrals: $\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos^2 \frac{x}{2}+x\cos x)e^{\sin x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$I_1=\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin x}{x\cos^2 x}dx$$

With this integral, I can't solve. I think setting $x=\frac{\pi}{4}-t$ is ok. But it seeems to be wrong.

$$I_3=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos^2 \frac{x}{2}+x\cos x)e^{\sin x}dx$$

I'd tried to split this integral, and then using method similar $I_1$ . But I can't get the result :( . And I need your help! Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want an answer to this question, and what have you tried to find one? Where do these integrals come from, and what is $I_2$ supposed to be? You have some votes to close this question because you have just asked a bare question without giving any context. There is perhaps something interesting going on here, but it isn't obvious to me what it is.

Comment: Just because you post two integrals of "above average complexity" (as MSE posts go) does not excuse the "bare-bones" posting of a question (two questions, to be exact) with no context or text explaining why you are interested in evaluating the integrals. $$ $$And to upvoters: I suspect there's a bit of a *double-standard* reflected in your votes.

Answer (score 3):

This is a partial answer as I only solve $I_3$, not $I_1$ yet.
$$
I_3=\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^2\big(\frac{x}{2}\big) e^{\sin x} dx +\int_0^{\pi/2} x\cos x e^{\sin x}dx.
$$
We can use a trig identity $2\cos^2(x/2)=(1+\cos x)$ on the first integral to obtain
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^2\big(\frac{x}{2}\big) e^{\sin x} dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{\sin x}dx +\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos x e^{\ sin x} dx=\frac{\pi}{4} \big(L_o(1)+I_0(1)\big)+\frac{1}{2}(e-1)
$$
where the first integral is given by the Struvel function L, and the modified Bessel function of the first kind I.  The second integral is trivially done by using $u=\sin x$.   We can now re-write $I_3$ as
$$
I_3=\frac{\pi}{4} \big(L_o(1)+I_0(1)\big)+\frac{1}{2}(e-1)+\int_0^{\pi/2} x\cos x e^{\sin x}dx.$$
This last integral can also be expressed in terms of Struvel and modified Bessel functions, but we first use partial integration to notice this, $u=x, du=dx, dv=\cos x \exp(\sin x)dx,v= \exp(\sin x)$, thus we obtain
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} x\cos x e^{\sin x}dx=\frac{\pi e}{2}-\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{\sin x}dx= \frac{\pi}{2} \big(e-L_0(1)-I_0(1)\big),
$$
Thus we can simplify $I_3$ and write
$$
I_3=\frac{1}{4} \big(2e(1+\pi)-\pi (L_0(1)+I_0(1))-2\big)
$$

Note: Struvel L function http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/StruveL/.  The modified bessel function $I_0$ is given by 
$$
I_0(z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{z\cos x}dx, \to \quad 
I_0(1)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{\cos x}dx.
$$
$$
L_0(1)=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{\sin x} dx-I_0(1)=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{\sin x} dx-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{\cos x}dx.
$$